# Concise partial application of ES2018 Async Generator?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2018

I have an async generator function defined, and want to create a second async generator function that is a partial application of the first function. For example, this works:

```js
async function* fn1(a, b) {/* do something */}

async function* fn2() {
  const a1 = fn1(0, 0);
  for await (const value of a1) {
    yield value;
  }
}
```

My question is: is there a more concise way to define `fn2`?

Comment: I don't see any "partial" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn1` returns the async iterable that `fn2` is iterating over, so rather than iterating manually in `fn2`, you can just yield the iterable created from `fn1` and let `fn2`'s consumer handle it:

```
async function* fn2() {
  yield* fn1(0, 0);
}
```

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function* fn1(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await delay(1000);
    yield i;
  }
}

async function* fn2() {
  yield* fn1(0, 0);
}

(async () => {
  for await (const val of fn2()) {
    console.log('Consumer got', val);
  }
  console.log('Done');
})();
```

```js
// Original version, without yield* (just to illustrate equivalence):

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function* fn1(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await delay(1000);
    yield i;
  }
}

async function* fn2() {
  const a1 = fn1(0, 0);
  for await (const value of a1) {
    yield value;
  }
}

(async () => {
  for await (const val of fn2()) {
    console.log('Consumer got', val);
  }
  console.log('Done');
})();
```

Comment: Ah! `yield*` was the syntax I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: You might want to add in a `return` keyword so that the eventual result of the generator gets propagated as well

Answer (score 0):

The most concise definition can be achieved by simply not making `fn2` a generator function. Use a normal function that returns a generator - the generator created by the call to `fn1`:

```
function fn2() {
  return fn1(0, 0);
}
```